# How to call a function in all inheritant classes?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, virtual-functions

For example let's say I have this class:

```
class base{
public:
    update();
};
```

and I have a lot of classes that are inherit from this one:

```
class A : public base 
{
    //<...>
}

class B : public base
{
    //<...>
}
```

and so i want to know - can i somehow call the function `base::update();` in all the classes without writing it all out (`A::update(); B::update();`) etc. 
Like calling one function that would do the `update();` in all the classes that inherit it from the base class.

Thanks!

Edit:
What I'm doing is changing my entity system into component based one and I want to know whether there's an easier way to call the (let's say) update(); function, that is inherited, in all the members. Instead of doing enemy01.update(); enemy02.update(); etc. to just write down a single update(); that'd work on all classes that have it(inherited it), sorta like a message to all of them to call the function.

Comment: I think you should try to write a real program before asking this.  It looks like you'll run into other questions before you run into this one.  You're misunderstanding some other things.

Comment: That's an *instance* member function, you need an instance when calling it.

Comment: I think you should state what high-level problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

A `virtual function`?

```
class base{
public:
    virtual void update();
};
```

And then this function:

```
void update_class(base &b) {
    return b.update();
}
```

You can call `update_class` on any class that inherits `base`.

Comment: The problem is I'd still have to write it all out, like for every class I'd have to call the function separately and so it would fix the problem it'd just change it, what i want to do is call ONE function and have it force every class that inherits from the base to do update();.

Comment: @Borisas You would be better off studying various design patterns such as this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern  That's why I asked in my other comment "what is the high-level problem you're tyring to solve?"